# Java using relation in generics type argument

Tags: java, generics

Currently I have this setup:

```
public abstract class Manager<B extends Bean, C extends AbstractConstraint> { 
    public final int insert(B b);

    public final boolean update(B b);

    public final boolean delete(B b);

    public final B get(C... c);

    public final List<B> search(C... c);

    public final List<B> getAll();
}

public interface Bean { }

public abstract class AbstractConstraint { }
```

concretely used in:

```
public class AccountManager extends Manager<AccountBean, AccountConstraint> { }

public class AccountBean implements Bean { }

public class AccountConstraint extends AbstractConstraint { }
```

A few remarks:

- `Bean` is the lowest entity possible. This is the direct instance of a row from a table in the database.
- A concrete implementation of `AbstractConstraint` should not implement/extend a concrete implementation of `Bean`, unless I am mistaken here.

Via the `Manager` I can be sure that all you can pass in is a concrete version of `<Bean, AbstractConstraint>`.

However currently it is entirely valid to define this:

```
public class BogusManager extends Manager<AccountBean, CharacterConstraint> { }
```

which makes no sense at all, how can I restrict the code such that this is not allowed anymore?

I think that I have two options:

1) Change `AccountConstraint` to `AccountConstraint<AccountBean>`, but I do not think that it would be valid since the type argument would not be used in `AccountConstraint` itself.

2) Have a way to define a relation `R` and let `Manager` check if `<B, C>` is in relation `R`, in other words you would need to check `R(B, C)`. But you would also need to be able to define a relation `R<AccountBean, AccountConstraint>` then, which would mean that `R = Manager`, but I don't think that it could be true. Anyway, how would I be able to implement this if it would be true?

Regards.

Comment: If constraints never use the type they constrain, why are they related to them? That is, why does `Manager<AccountBean, CharacterConstraint>` make no sense but `Manager<AccountBean, AccountConstraint>` does, even though the constraints don't seem to do anything specific to the bean?

Comment: Or, to put it another way: maybe the parallel class hierarchies are the design smell you should get rid of if there isn't even any strong coupling between them.

Comment: Well `AccountConstraint` does constrain `AccountBean`, so I think the design flaw was there. Even though I see no use of the type parameter in `AccountConstraint` itself.

Comment: My point is, how does it constrain `AccountBean` specifically, if it never refers to that type?

Comment: The API for contraints does not need to *parametrically* use the type of the bean being constrained.  That is, `AbstractConstraint< T >` might not make use of the `T` in its API (although frankly, that seems kind of smelly), while `AccountConstraint <: AbstractConstraint< AccountBean >` might indeed use special knowledge of `AccountBean` in its implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option is legal, you do not need to use type variable.

For the second option, you need to pass class instances of `bean` and `constraint` to manager constructor which will check if this is legal pair. As far as I know there is no way to implement such check in source only, i.e. add declarative constraint to source code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should satisfy a compile-time version of option 2:

```
interface Witness< B, C > {}

public final class AccountConstraintsForAccountsOnly implements Witness< AccountBean, AccountConstraint > {}
public final class CharacterConstraintsForCharactersOnly implements Witness< CharacterBean, CharacterConstraint > {}

public abstract class Manager< B extends Bean, C extends AbstractConstraint, W extends Witness< B, C > { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Option 1

```
 //add a Type    
abstract class AbstractConstraint<T>{}
//Type is tied to your Concrete bean
abstract class Manager<B extends Bean, C extends AbstractConstraint<B> >
{
.
.
.
}
```

While implementing the  `Constraint`, state what type of `Constraint` it is, by just passing the `Bean` Type

Ex.

```
 class BogusBean implements Bean { }
 class BogusConstraint extends AbstractConstraint<BogusBean> { }
 class BogusManager extends Manager<BogusBean, BogusConstraint> {}
```

Comment: I believe this is option 1 in the OP